# IOS Core Image Filter Parameter

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, imagefilter

In my app I'm trying to apply a CIFilter (CIBumpDistortion) to my image. 
My problem is when using the kcIInputCenterKey parameter, it seems I have to give numbered coordinates. When I run the app, this code returns the left eye coordinates:

```
if (face.hasLeftEyePosition) {
                NSLog("Left eye %g %g", face.leftEyePosition.x, face.leftEyePosition.y);

Hence, I can manually then enter the left eye coordinates into the kCInputCenterKey and then run the app again and the filter is applied to the left eye centre point:

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBumpDistortion")
            filter?.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
            filter?.setValue(200, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

            filter?.setValue(CIVector(x:150, y: 150), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey)
            if let output = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
                self.chosenImage?.image = UIImage(cgImage: context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!)
```

However, as I wish the user to be able to pick any image to use, I need Xcode to find the left eye position and apply the filter to the area, without me having to manually enter the coordinates.

I have tried using strings, different types, etc in place of the numbers required for the x and y coordinates, all with no luck.

Any help would be hugely welcome and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm reading things. The user needs to pick an image from an unknown source (camera? photo album? camera roll?).

- If the user-selected image is from a static set of images, you'll need to find the X/Y values manually and store their values in code before passing them to the filter.
- If the user-selected image is completely unknown before the selection, you really should have **the user**, not **Xcode** dictate where the left eye is. (While you could try the edge detection filter I think you'll have a harder time being correct.)

In the latter case I'd consider adding 2-4 gesture recognizers, tap for the initial point, pinch to resize the area, and maybe rotate (to rotate) and pan (to move).

Comment: Hi, dfd, Many thanks for your suggestions. I'm relatively new to coding in general and never would have thought to try gesture recognizers! Thanks again, I'll give it another go.